# How to add event listener for multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a page with 5 input fields. How do I add a blur event listener on them together?

I get an error when I try

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').addEventListener('blur', e => {
  console.log('blur on input')
})
```

EDIT 1

I am able to add eventListeners to individual items like so,

```
const allInputs = [...document.getElementsByTagName('input')]
allInputs.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('blur', (e) => console.log('blur') ))
```

But is there a way to add a collective event listener on HTMLCollection?

Comment: Also, try event delegation using event capturing.

Answer (score 0):

> The Element method [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

You have to loop through all the elements to attach the event (`blur`) individually like the following way:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(el){
   el.addEventListener('blur', e => {
      console.log('blur on input')
   });
});
```

Comment: You can handle in a single event listener for multiple elements

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Adding a event listener to document and capturing the target when the event bubbles.

```js
document.addEventListener("focusout",function(event){
    if(event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) //can also be used as elem.target.tagName.toLowerCase()=="input"
    {
        console.log("Using focusout : "+event.target.id);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
document.addEventListener("blur",function(event){
    if(event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) //can also be used as elem.target.tagName.toLowerCase()=="input"
    {
        console.log("Using blur : "+event.target.id);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
},true);
```

```html
<input id="1">
<input id="2">
<input id="3">
<input id="4">
<input id="5">
```

`true` in the `blur` event is to make it bubble.

MDN Docs for [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur), [focusout event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout)

Refer this [nice article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) for more info.